# Query to set variables based on matching id in a row in the resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a resultset with one row per role, how do I set my three variables like IsAdmin, IsSuperUser, IsUser.

I tried this, but it's super ugly. I want to accomplish the same with just one query. I know how to combine them into one query with three subqueries but I'd like to get away with only one query if it's possible.

```
declare @IsAdmin bit, @IsSuperUser bit, @IsUser bit
select RoleId into #CallerRoles from AspNetUserRoles aur where aur.UserId = @CallerUserId 
set @IsAdmin = case when exists (select * from #CallerRoles where RoleId = 1) then 1 else 0 end
set @IsSuperUser = case when exists (select * from #CallerRoles where RoleId = 3) then 1 else 0 end
set @IsUser = case when exists (select * from #CallerRoles where RoleId = 5) then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Questions with working code that you want to improve belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Why use 3 variables to hold the role type of a single row? Or do you expect the user to have *multiple* rows?

Comment: Given code is more like a workaround

Comment: Yes, users can have multiple rows

Comment: You haven't explained what the actual problem is. Why use 3 variables at all? That's where the problem starts.

Comment: If you want to check the highest role of a user you could use `SELECT MIN(RoleID). ... Where UserID=@id` for example. You can use that as a subquery in any other query that needs to know a user's role.

Comment: These variables go into a where clause later on, to narrow down a resultset, I did not find it relevant to the question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos or maybe I can do order by descending into #CallerRoles and then try the first role first by top 1 because most of them are regular users, not a bad idea

Comment: It's relevant to the question, because you can use a subquery instead of two separate queries. Or you may need only *one* variable instead of 3. Using a separate query is already ugly in itself and causes concurrency issues - what if the data changes from one query to the next?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set your variables `IsAdmin`, `IsSuperUser`, and `IsUser` in  one query, you can use the conditional aggregation like the following:

```sql
DECLARE @IsAdmin BIT, @IsSuperUser BIT, @IsUser BIT

SELECT
    @IsAdmin = MAX(CASE WHEN RoleId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    @IsSuperUser = MAX(CASE WHEN RoleId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    @IsUser = MAX(CASE WHEN RoleId = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    AspNetUserRoles
WHERE
    UserId = @CallerUserId
```

In this query, the `MAX` function is used with conditional expression (`CASE WHEN`) inside. Each conditional expression checks the `RoleId` and assigns either 1 or 0 based on the condition. The result of each one is then the aggregation using `MAX` to obtain a single value for each variable.

Note that the query assumes that the `AspNetUserRoles` table contains the columns `RoleId` and `UserId`, which are used for filtering the data. Adjust the table and column names as per your schema.

Comment: <pedantry> [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a conditional _expression_, not _statement_. </pedantry>

Comment: i would wrap in coalesce ... with minimum role in case null

Answer (score 1):

With no sample data I can't test this of course but you can aggregate, something like

```
select 
    @IsAdmin = IsNull(max(case when RoleId = 1 then 1 end),0)
    @IsSuperUser = IsNull(max(case when RoleId = 3 then 1 end),0)
    @IsUser = IsNull(max(case when RoleId = 5 then 1 end),0)
from #CallerRoles;
```